# Where is the Foucault pendulum in Mainz?

Tags: physics, reference-request

A Foucault pendulum in Mainz is [listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Foucault_pendulums#Germany). The article says that it is in

> School for Business and Technique, Mainz

However, I didn't find any information about this pendulum on the Internet. I know that this question is not fully in the profile of this site, but maybe someone know that

> where exactly is this Foucault pendulum and when is it visitable.

Comment: Could that be a mixup with (or move to) nearby Frankfurt am **Main**, where the [Experiminta](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiminta) Museum [has](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Foucault_Pendel.JPG) one, half an hour away and missing from the wiki list?

Comment: Google books led to a novel:
Title Das Mainzer Mörderpendel
Author Jean C. Becker
Publisher Selztal-Verlag, 2005
ISBN 393692905X, 9783936929058
Length 187 pages

Comment: Searching German websites, I cannot find any "{Fach}{hoch}schule für Wirtschaft und Technik" in Mainz. The closest match to the description might be "Hochschule Mainz / University of Applied Sciences". However, I an unable to find any mention of a "Foucault-Pendel" or "Foucaultsches Pendel" in this school or in fact anywhere in Mainz. The Wikipedia entry would appear to be out-of-date or in error.

Comment: I grew up near and studied at the University in Mainz and I have never heard of a Foucault pendulum at any school or the university. That doesn't settle this question definitely, but I would be very surprised..

Comment: Thank you for the answers. @FrancoisZiegler Thank you the information about the Foucault pendulum in Frankfurt am Main. If you summarize the comments in an answer, I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of comments, per OP’s request:

- As observed by @njuffa, there is no apparent trace of a Foucault pendulum at (closest match) [Hochschule Mainz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Applied_Sciences,_Mainz)’s School of Business (Wirtschaft) nor School of Engineering (Technik).
- Could it, then, be a mixup with — or relocation to — nearby [Experiminta Museum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiminta) in Frankfurt am **Main**, which  [does](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Foucault_Pendel.JPG) have one, half an hour away and missing from the wiki list?